# Can heroku config vars be boolean and can ejs access it?

Tags: node.js, heroku, ejs

Can I set `process.env.production` to `true` or will it be converted to `"true"`?

I.e. Must config vars in Heroku always be strings, or can they be boolean?

Also: If an `if/else` condition in my `index.ejs` executes on `process.env.production` being set to `true`, will it be evaluated before being rendered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All heroku config vars will be environment variables, which, in linux environments, can only be strings.

So all your variables will be strings once in your app.
Nothing prevents you from doing the following though:

```
var is_production = process.env.production === 'true'
```

Comment: don't you mean `if (process.env.production) var is_production = true;`?

Comment: No. My code comment will define the `is_production` variable no matter what (setting it to false if it's not production), while your solution will not set the variable at all if it's not production.

Comment: Ah, thanks. My code was only aiming to set it to true, and leave it undefined otherwise, since that would still evaluate `(!is_production)` as `true`